# Group data into specified intervals satisfying certain condition

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

I'd like to sort into new lists those items in this list...

```
truc = [['12', 'brett', 5548],
       ['22.3', 'troy', 9514],
       ['8.1', 'hings', 12635],
       ['34.2', 'dab', 17666],
       ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065],
       ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]]
```

... grouping them using the last field, into bins of size 3500
So, the ideal result would be this:

```
firstSort = [['34.2', 'dab', 17666],
            ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065],
            ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]]

secondSort = [['22.3', 'troy', 9514],
             ['8.1', 'hings', 12635]]

lastSort = ['12', 'brett', 5548]
```

I tried to use the `itertools.groupby()` function, but i am not capable of find a way to specify the bin size.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to mean that the size of the bins would be 3500. I will edit. Thanks!

Comment: If the last field values are 0, 3000 and 6000, what will be the pairing? `[0,3000], [6000]`, or `[0], [3000,6000]`, or `[0,3000,6000]`?

Comment: would it be enough to specify a function that returns the integer result of key division by 3500? This might group items in a less-than-optimal way, though.

Comment: @jwpat7: Don't you think that he simply mistyped 180688 instead of 18068, which would be logical if you look at the other values?

Comment: @BrtH yes that was it...

Comment: @Alok the pairing will be: [0,3000] [3000,6000]. The number can happen more than once in different bins.

Comment: peixe, I undid downvote.  By "bins of size 3500", do you mean bin limits 3500 apart, or 3500 items in a bin?  If latter, wouldn't all 6 items of example go in same bin?

Comment: @jwpat7 No, it would be that the bin limits are 3500 apart.

Comment: @peixe can you take sometime and put down how exactly this grouping works?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: Do you mean I report how does your proposed solution works on my data? Or should I explain better how do i want the grouping?

Comment: @peixe I am not sure the way I grouped them is what you want, because you talk about bin size without explaining what it means, you say an item can be in two groups, with my solution it will never happen, so yes explain better

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: Yes, your solution looks good, but i need the item to be in all possible groups. Example: (assuming bin size = 3500)
A:20
B:6000
C:7500
D:10000
*The bin split should always start with the lowest value
Then, the grouping would be:
[A],[B,C],[C,D]
Is it clearer? ;)

Comment: @peixe it looks very artifical grouping what if I increment each by 1 i.e. 21, 6001, 7501, 10001 does grouping change now, why?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal : No, the grouping shouldn't change! The bins keep the same size [A],[B,C],[C,D]. Anyway, your solution gave me a hint on how to do it... I'll keep trying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial to do without itertools

```
truc = [['12', 'brett', 5548],
       ['22.3', 'troy', 9514],
       ['8.1', 'hings', 12635],
       ['34.2', 'dab', 17666],
       ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065],
       ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]]

truc.sort(key=lambda a:a[-1])
groups = [[]]
last_row = None
for row in truc:
    if last_row is not None and row[-1] - last_row[-1] > 3500:
        groups.append([])
    last_row = row
    groups[-1].append(row)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(groups)
```

Output:

```
[[['12', 'brett', 5548]],
 [['22.3', 'troy', 9514], ['8.1', 'hings', 12635]],
 [['34.2', 'dab', 17666], ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065], ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]]]
```

Comment: Not EXACTLY what I wanted to do, but it may give a pretty hint.

Answer (score 1):

A basic binner with `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from math import floor

# data must be sorted

data = [ ['12', 'brett', 5548],
       ['22.3', 'troy', 9514],
       ['8.1', 'hings', 12635],
       ['34.2', 'dab', 17666],
       ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065],
       ['4q3', 'delta', 18068] ]

groups = []
for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x: floor(x[-1]/3500)):
    groups.append(list(g))

print groups
```

Returns:

```
[
    [
        ['12', 'brett', 5548]
    ],
    [
        ['22.3', 'troy', 9514]
    ],
    [
        ['8.1', 'hings', 12635]
    ],
    [
        ['34.2', 'dab', 17666],
        ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065],
        ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]
    ]
]
```

You can then coalesce the groups when the maximum of one group less the minimum of the group before turns out to be less than 3500. You would then get,

```
[
    [
        ['12', 'brett', 5548]
    ],
    [
        ['22.3', 'troy', 9514],
        ['8.1', 'hings', 12635]
    ],
    [
        ['34.2', 'dab', 17666],
        ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065],
        ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]
    ]
]
```

Even with coalescing after the `groupby`, I think that Anurag Uniyal's solution would still achieve better grouping in the average case.

Answer (score 0):

using `defaultdict()`:

```
lis=[['12', 'brett', 5548],
      ['22.3', 'troy', 9514],
      ['8.1', 'hings', 12635],
      ['34.2', 'dab', 17666],
      ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065],
      ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]]

from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    not_append=True
    for y in d:
        for z in d[y]:
            if abs(z[-1]-x[-1])<=3500:
                d[y].append(x)
                not_append=False
                break
    else:
        if not_append:
            d[i].append(x)
print d.values()
```

**output:**

```
[[['12', 'brett', 5548]],
 [['22.3', 'troy', 9514], ['8.1', 'hings', 12635]], 
 [['34.2', 'dab', 17666], ['4q3', 'sigma', 18065], ['4q3', 'delta', 18068]]
]
```